# SetFocus is not working after setting the QHeaderView in QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qheaderview

Following is the code that I'm using:

```
pHeaderView->setMovable(false); 
pHeaderView->setClickable(true);
pHeaderView->setDefaultAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter); 
pHeaderView->setTextElideMode(Qt::ElideRight); 
tableView->setHorizontalHeader(pHeaderView);
tableView->setModel(model);
tableView->setCurrentIndex(model->index(0, 1));
tableView->selectionModel()->select(model->index(0, 1), QItemSelectionModel::Select);
```

On removing the  QHeaderView, I'm able to set the focus on the QTableView
I want to set the header as well as set the keyboard focus on the QTableView.

Comment: tableView->selectionModel()->setCurrentIndex(index)

Comment: @Programmer_ARM: This is not working.

Comment: I have set: tableView->selectionModel()->setCurrentIndex(model->index(0, 1),QItemSelectionModel::Select);

Comment: Am I doing something wrong here?